# bigbluebutton setting.yml viewersInWebcam parameter is not working as expected

Tags: bigbluebutton, ant-media-server-sdk

The parameter `viewersInWebcam` placed under /usr/share/meteor/bundle/programs/server/assets/app/config/settings.yml is not working as expected. What is the role of this parameter? As the name suggested it is controlling number of viewers webcam in a meeting. I set it 2 but all 6 viewers who joined the meetings were able to see the webcam of the other users.
Is there any setting where we can say only the current user and the presenter webcam will be streamed? If yes, where we can do that (filename and path).
These parameters are set as follows:
`enableLimitOfViewersInWebcam: true viewersInWebcam: 2`

Comment: I think this question is more likely about bigbluebutton

Answer (score 0):

You should set enableLimitOfViewersInWebcam = true

Comment: i did that but still everyone can share webcam. more than 'viewersInWebcam'

Comment: Sharing webcam is not limited. Viewing is limited. And also its just for normal users not moderators i think.